# What does request_source do in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am picking up some old Django code and am puzzled by a line in the site's master template.

After a series of `{% load xxx %}` lines there is the line

```
{% request_source 849051 %}
```

I have been unsuccessful in finding any documentation for this command.  Is it a standard template command? Or is it something custom to this code, and if so where would I likely find the implementation?

The site was written for Django 1.5.12 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{%load ... %}` loads various python routines from the templatetags directory of an installed django app (in installed_apps in settings.py) think of this like `import package` but you are limitted to packages only available inside the templatetag folder of an installed app

`{% funciton_call arg1 arg2 ... %}` is calling a function defined in the python files in the templatetags directory

`request_source` is not a django thing, it is a function in one of the templatetag files

Comment: If it is not a django thing what is it doing in the source?  It seems to run without an error.

Comment: edited to clarify ... you are effectively importing it with one of the load directives...